# Setting up SAP BI Web Intelligence Application

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Afternoon all,

I'm going out of my mind and need some help! I have SAP BI and BO but, for some reason, I do not have the Web Intelligence Application in "Preferences" or "Applications".

There doesn't seem to be any guides about how you add the application, can anyone help?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Web Intelligence was selected when the software was installed, you just need your user ID to have access to it.  Log in to CMC, go to Applications, and select Web Intelligence.  In User Rights, give your user ID at least "View" permission.

Comment: When I installed Crystal Server 2013 - I selected everything for a full installation. If I log into CMC > Applications, there is no Web Intelligence. This is where I'm getting really confused....

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Crystal Server installation doesn't include WebI.  You should be using BI Platform, which includes services for both.

Comment: Ah balls ok! So I need to download BI Edge, for example?

Comment: Just struggling to get any files from SAP at the moment :) all the downloads seem to be corrupted